# Stuck at a writing a c code, please consider give me guidances

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm writing a C program.

The code use a function which returns the number of neighboring cells which are occupied by an organism.

The code starts with an initial configuration of occupied spaces and creates a new space by applying two simple rules to the previous generation.

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //creating memory space for a grid
    int row, col, i, j, k, l, m, n;
    char a, b, c, d;
    char grid[10][10];
    row = 10;
    col = 10;

    //setting entire grid to '-'
    a = '-';
    for (i = 0; i< row; i++){
        for(j = 0; j< col; j++){
        grid[i][j] = a;
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump the code and say "it doesn't work, fix it!". Describe the specific problem you are having and what your specific question is.

Comment: @AlanAu, I think he both described his problem well and showed effort in trying, it should be fairly clear looking at his code that he is just struggling with how to implement the next step in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code in two steps, both codes are below with comments explaining what I did. I should mention (and put in bold) that the **your code has out of bounds array references and the code I posted still has out of bounds references**. You need to handle cases in the `occ` function when checking `x == 0`, `y == 0`, `x == 9`, and `y == 9` in a different way to avoid out of bounds references

The first modification was just to simplify your code, you had a lot of variables (more than you need) and some duplicated code. Below is basically a code reduction:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char grid[10][10];

// Moved this function here
int occ(int x, int y) {
    int i, j, count;
    char gridCopy[10][10];

    // Just trying to make a copy of the original grid to work on
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            gridCopy[i][j] = grid[i][j];

    // Checking on the value of the neighboring cells
    count = 0;
    if (gridCopy[x-1][y+1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x][y+1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x+1][y+1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x-1][y] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x+1][y] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x-1][y-1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x][y-1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (gridCopy[x+1][y-1] == '*')
        count++;

    return count;
}

// You probably are going to do this often in the future
// Make a function for it instead of having the same code often
void printGrid() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, j;

    // Setting entire grid to '-'
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            grid[i][j] = '-'; // No need for a variable, just use '-' directly

    // Printing out grid
    printf("This is the original array\n");
    printGrid();

    // Setting a few random places to '*'
    grid[2][3] = '*'; // No need for a variable, just use '*' directly
    grid[3][4] = '*'; // No need for a variable, just use '*' directly
    grid[7][2] = '*'; // No need for a variable, just use '*' directly
    grid[8][1] = '*'; // No need for a variable, just use '*' directly

    // Printing out grid
    printf("This is the new array\n");
    printGrid();

    printf("The number of neighbors is: %d\n", occ(2, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

The second modification was to calculate the new state of the array after determining what lives, dies, or comes to life (is born). I modified you `occ` function to instead return `'-'` or `'*'`. The new state is calculated based on the original state and then the new state overwrites the old state. This is important to do in Conway's Game of Life because without a copy the changes in life and death will affect the next iteration of calculating life and death:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char grid[10][10];

// Instead of returning the count this now returns '-' or '*'
char occ(int x, int y) {
    // Calculate based on the old state (grid)
    int count = 0;
    if (grid[x-1][y+1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x][y+1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x+1][y+1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x-1][y] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x+1][y] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x-1][y-1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x][y-1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[x+1][y-1] == '*')
        count++;

    if (grid[x][y] == '-') { // If the cell was dead...
        if (count == 3)
            return '*'; // The cell came to life
        else
            return '-'; // The cell is still dead
    }
    else { // If the cell was alive...
        if (count == 2 || count == 3)
            return '*'; // The cell is still alive
        else
            return '-'; // The cell died
    }
}

void printGrid() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            grid[i][j] = '-';

    grid[2][3] = '*';
    grid[2][5] = '*'; // Added this so that everything does not die
    grid[3][4] = '*';
    grid[7][2] = '*';
    grid[8][1] = '*';

    printf("Original state\n");
    printGrid();

    // Calculate the new state
    char gridCopy[10][10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            gridCopy[i][j] = occ(i, j);

    // Copy the new state into the old state
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            grid[i][j] = gridCopy[i][j];

    printf("New state\n");
    printGrid();

    return 0;
}
```

If you have questions I'd be happy to answer, I have done Conway's Game of Life before

Comment: Thank you so much! I literally have tears in my eyes! do you want to email me, my email address is debasedollar@gmail.com, feel free to email if you want, I don't you want to give you your email address in public!

Comment: Your welcome, my email is simes (dot) alex (at) gmail (dot) com

Comment: Thanks, I just emailed you!